# Error 'Object has no method xxx ' while using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use Mongoose for connecting MongoDB with Nodejs .

I have my code as below. When I am trying to do a GET/POST via api/users I get the

Error

---

```
TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
[08/14 21:28:06 GMT+0800]     if (!(this instanceof model))
[08/14 21:28:06 GMT+0800]       return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
[08/14 21:28:06 GMT+0800]     Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
[08/14 21:28:06 GMT+0800]   } has no method 'list'
```

---

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong ? I had to split my code into different files because I have a lot of functions and I dont want to mess them either my app.js or index/routes.js

**app.js**

```
//database connection 
mongoose.connect('....');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
 console.log("Conncection Success !");
});

users_module= require('./custom_modules/users.js');

users_module.init_users();
...
    app.get('/api/users',user.list);  // routing code from expressjs
```

**/custom_modules/users.js**

```
function init_users() {

    userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        //id: Number,
        usernamename: String,
        hash: String,
        ...

    });

    userSchema.methods.list = list;

    UserModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

}

function list() {
    return UserModel.find(function (err, users) {
        if (!err) {
            return users;
        } else {
            return console.log(err);

        }
    });
});

exports.init_users = init_users;
```

**routes/user.js**

```
exports.list = function (req, res){

    var users = UserModel.list();  // <---------- This is the error Line 
    return res.send(users);

}
```

Comment: On which line did you see that error?

Comment: I updated the error on the Question . And also pointed out the Line where the error occurs . The error occurs inside the routes/user.js

Comment: `UserModel` doesn't have a `list` method. You added it to the instances of `UserModel` by using `methods.` You could do `UserModel.list = list` to add it.

Comment: If I do userSchema.list= list, will that help also ?

Comment: Hi @WiredPrairie , Please put that as an answer and I will accept it . You were right . It worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `methods` property of a `model` object in Mongoose is used to add functions to instances of model objects.  So, in your code, the function `list` is added to an instance of `UserModel`. If you instead want to have a `static` like singleton function, then you could add it directly to the `UserModel` object returned by the call to `mongoose.model('UserModel', userModelSchema);`:

```
UserModel.list = list;
```

Now, you can call it to return the list of all users.

Note that it's still an asynchronous function though. So, you can't just return the results of calling the function, as it will be empty normally. `find` is async, so your `list` function also needs to accept a callback that can be called when the list has been returned:

```
UserModel.list(function(list) {
   res.render(list);
});
```

Comment: The last paragraph of yours makes things a lot clearer to me. Thanks ! I understand now .

Comment: Static methods can also be defined by using the keyword statics - animalSchema.statics.findByName = function (name, cb){ }